# Data validation using Informatica's DVO tool

Tags: informatica

How do I check whether the Join view created in Informatica DVo tool is correct and gives some output.

Because if I create Single table or Table pair, the test cases show a Yellow triangle sign (means no data satisfying the condition).

Please help me to validate the join and the test created.

Comment: You need to provide some input Jan of what you're doing.

Comment: I have created a Join view and I need to validate it if its fetching any records. In order to do that, I have created a Single table using the join and the market identifier column as Primary key. Added a test case to fetch the 'count' but on executing the Single table, it doesn't give any output and throws the yellow mark

Comment: Also what do these Pink and yellow mark symbolize so that I can check just that part of code for any errors.